# Unable to upgrade from SQL Server 2012 evaluation to Standard

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I was using SQL Sever 2012 Evaluation edition. As it was about to expire, we purchased a Standard edition license.
I was told that I don't need the lisence key as it was embedded in the ISO installation file. However, when trying to run the installation file, I get the message - There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer.
The reason for this is that the edition that I was trying to install was 2012 SP1, which is the version that I was already on.
When trying to do the upgrade using the Configuration manager and then choosing maintainance -> Upgrade, I get asked for the product key, which I don't have.
The advice from the Microsoft account manager was to let my product expire and then try the upgrade again. However after the product expired I still have exactly the same issue.

Any advice besides uninstalling SQL and reinstalling?

Thanks,
Niel

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run an 'Edition Upgrade' of an existing SQL Server instance, even on an expired evaluation, you can do it via the SQL Server setup from the Installation media, and SQL Server Installation Center, by clicking on 'Maintenance', then 'Edition Upgrade' and follow the rest of the installation from there.

The error message is generally caused by applying incorrect versions (patched up, language incorrect etc.) on an instance that is different.  The 'Select features' page has a description message on the top right side of the page explaining what is ocurring.  I'd suggest taking a look there first of all.

Please check this post, although it relates to 2008 R2, the error fix is the same in 2012 :-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c82da968-bbfb-4803-a9b2-876776f033d6/there-are-no-sql-server-instances-or-shared-features-that-can-be-updated-on-this-computer?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

This should have the answers that you need.

Regards,

Dave